# Index boolean values to Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file with different columns. I want to only show the lines that contain the word 'DUC' in the Column 'Comentário' .

```
df = pd.read_excel('lista1.xlsx')
coment = df['Comentário']
duc = coment.str.contains("DUC") 
df[df['Comentário'] = coment.str.contains("DUC")]
```

Comment: Add an example of your dataset in text format, mostly 5 - 10 rows is enough, we cannot run or see `lista1.xlsx`. Besides that, I think you want `df[df['Comentário'].str.contains('DUC')]`, so for now I will close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
print(df[df['Comentário'].str.contains("DUC")])
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you